# Positioning a Module in a For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, position

everyone, I am having a problem with my store and its sub-module's positioning. So I have a `Store` and a `StoreModule` class that work together. What I have in my `Map`, or `Level` class, and in the constructor I call this code:

```
store = new Store(Tile.TILE_SIZE, 0, 0, 3, 8, 2, Sprite.grass);
```

Now let's take a little insight into my `Store` class that runs this code.

```
public Store(int size, int x, int y, int pad, int cols, int rows, Sprite sprite) {
    this.cols = cols;
    this.rows = rows;
    mods = new StoreModule[cols * rows];

    for (int yy = 0; yy < cols; yy++) {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < rows; xx++) {
        System.out.println("xx:" + xx + ", yy:" + yy + " ; x:" + (x + size * xx + pad * xx) + ", y:" + (y + size * yy + pad * yy));
            mods[xx + yy * rows] = new StoreModule(x + size * xx + pad * xx, y + size * yy + pad * yy, Sprite.rock);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works fine and all.. but the thing is I set it to have `8 columns` and `2 rows`, but when it creates, it gives me `2 columns` and `8 rows`. I know this is having the error in the Store class because I printed out the values of `xx`, `yy`, `x`, and `y`.

When I run this, this is my output:

```
xx:0, yy:0 ; x:0, y:0
xx:1, yy:0 ; x:57, y:0
xx:0, yy:1 ; x:0, y:57
xx:1, yy:1 ; x:57, y:57
xx:0, yy:2 ; x:0, y:114
xx:1, yy:2 ; x:57, y:114
xx:0, yy:3 ; x:0, y:171
xx:1, yy:3 ; x:57, y:171
xx:0, yy:4 ; x:0, y:228
xx:1, yy:4 ; x:57, y:228
xx:0, yy:5 ; x:0, y:285
xx:1, yy:5 ; x:57, y:285
xx:0, yy:6 ; x:0, y:342
xx:1, yy:6 ; x:57, y:342
xx:0, yy:7 ; x:0, y:399
xx:1, yy:7 ; x:57, y:399
```

Which what needs to happen is the `x` and the `y` actually needs to be switched. I could easily fix this by putting the `x` where `y` goes, and `y` where `x` goes, but that seems like a cheap way to fix my problem. The only thing I know is the problem is in the `for loop` in the `Store` class.

**Summary**
I am creating a `Store` class that handles the creation of the `StoreModule`s in a grid pattern, and when I do this I use a `for loop`. The problem is that if I put the `columns` to be `8` and the `rows` to be `2`, it seems to flip those. How would I fix this? As I said, I could cheaply fix this by treating `columns` as `rows` and vice versa, or putting `x` where `y` goes and vice versa. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That kind of thing usually happens when you mistake x,y (coordinates) with *rows an columns*. In your code, x is the row an y is the column, but in an intuitive way of looking at the matrix it should be the other way around.

Comment: I actually thought I did have this mistaken, but I really don't. In my for loops, I have the `yy` running for `cols` and `xx` running for `rows`. As I said before if I were to just switch those it would be fixed, but I wouldn't like it considering that it isn't really correct.

Comment: I don't know how you intuitively look at a 2D array, but I see rows one *below* the other (at decreasing *y* coordinates), columns one *next to* another (in increasing *x* coordinates), so the way I see it, I associate x with columns and y with rows.